# How to update google map markers in updatepanel?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, webforms

I want to update the markers on google map. Google map div is inside a updatepanel. I tried calling map loading JavaScript function by various means but no luck. function is getting called but map showing only old markers not updated one. To regenerate the scenario, i am doing it on tick of timer in below. Ontick, repeater datasource table is getting updated but not markers data.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Key"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var markers = [
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                     {
                         "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                         "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                         "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                         "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                     }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            ];
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                LoadMap();
            };
            //On UpdatePanel Refresh
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            if (prm != null) {
                prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
                    if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                        LoadMap();
                    }
                });
            };
            function LoadMap() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    // alert(markers[i].description);
                    var data = markers[i]
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: data.title
                    });
                    (function (marker, data) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, data);
                }
            };
        </script>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="30000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = this.GetData("SELECT top 2 Name,lat as Latitude,long as Longitude,id as Description FROM tma_dump2 where city='Delhi' and id>10 ORDER BY Id");
        rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
        rptMarkers.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = this.GetData("SELECT top 2 Name,lat as Latitude,long as Longitude,id as Description FROM tma_dump2 where city='Mumbai' and id>10 ORDER BY Id");
    rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
    rptMarkers.DataBind();
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}


private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TMA"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's evident that i am doing something horribly wrong.
Please enlighten me.

Comment: something wrong in the design - the repeater (that needs the updatepanel) is out side the UpdatePanel - and the div that you render the map is inside the updatepanel (this div probably not need it). Why the UpdatePanel at the first place ?

Comment: @Aristos: Thanks for stopping. This is just a regenerated scenario. i am working on ecommerce plateform where items are displayed on map as well as in list. So user can add or remove item in or from cart.So to avoid reload of whole page, i am doing it in updatepanel.

Comment: @Aristos: I tried code after moving repeater inside update panel but no luck.!!